# Can we enable math notation?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On CS stack exchange, they use `$` to enable latex math statements.  Since teaching questions about theoretical CS would be applicable here, we might also need this.  How do we go about getting mathematical statements enabled?

Answer (score 12):

If you can read this…

$$
\Huge MathJax: ACTIVATED
$$

Comment: So far, 4/44 threads would be improved by it, and 1 of them is basically indecipherable without.  Is there some target that we need to meet before it can be enabled?

Comment: @Choirbean I put in the request. It should be enabled shortly.

Comment: $\TeX\text{}$ FTW!

Comment: @RobertCartaino Having $\TeX$ enabled greatly improves the quality of a site - thank you!  That said, it's really frustrating to lack it on other SE's.  Could you point me in the right direction for requesting it elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

This is a list of questions that would benefit from LaTeX. This answer is community wiki, so feel free to add questions. If you think a question should be removed from the list, please leave a comment.

- [Teaching Induction and Loop Invariants to Prove the Correctness of Algorithms](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6/teaching-induction-and-loop-invariants-to-prove-the-correctness-of-algorithms/)
- [In a course about Turing machines, how many questions like "Construct a Turing Machine that does X" should I include?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/84/in-a-course-about-turing-machines-how-many-questions-like-construct-a-turing-m)
- [The use of the Octal system](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/137/the-use-of-the-octal-system/138)
- [Presenting Mapping Reducibility (for P vs NP)](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/174/presenting-mapping-reducibility-for-p-vs-np/182)